# MSAL - Azure Transactable Offer - Read ID Token

Tags: azure, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I'm building a transactable Azure offer, and part of the requirement is to have a landing page that serves as a confirmation page. It receives a marketplace token, with information about the subscription.
How it works is that the user starts the purchase on Azure, and is then redirected to my landing page. On the landing page I need to enable SSO.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace/azure-ad-transactable-saas-landing-page#read-information-from-claims-encoded-in-the-id-token) also states that it sends an ID Token with the request, but it's not documented how that's being sent? When I check the HTTP request, there are no headers with that ID token. I can only see the "token" query string parameter with the marketplace token.

So, how can my landing page retrieve the ID token with information about the user?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to implement single sign-on (SSO) for your landing page, which will allow users to authenticate once and access multiple services without needing to re-enter their credentials. In order to retrieve the ID token with information about the user, you will need to configure Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) to send the ID token to your landing page.

Here are the general steps you can follow to configure SSO with Azure AD:

Register your application in Azure AD - You will need to create a new Azure AD application for your landing page and configure the appropriate permissions and authentication settings.

Configure authentication settings - You can configure Azure AD to use OpenID Connect as the authentication protocol, which will allow you to receive an ID token with user information.

Set up SSO for your landing page - You will need to configure your landing page to accept the ID token and use it to authenticate the user.

Test and deploy - Once you have configured SSO, you will need to test it thoroughly to ensure that it works as expected. You can then deploy your landing page and integrate it with Azure Marketplace.

Regarding the ID token that is sent with the request, it's possible that the token is being sent in the request body rather than the headers. You may want to check the documentation or contact Azure support for more information on how the ID token is being sent.

I hope this information helps! Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had to implement SSO and then I got the ID token with information about the user.